# Android NDK release Build method not found

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, native, ndk-build

I have a little problem with an native Android Libary.
I am calling a Method from native Code like this:

```
        clazz = env->FindClass("<package>/NativeInterface");;
        midlog = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "callStr", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clazz, midlog, jstr);
```

When I Build my App in Debug mode, I have no problems with this.
But when i Build in release mode, I get an error :

```
Throwing new exception 'no static method "L<package>/NativeInterface;.callStr(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Could it be that Android Studio is obforscating the java code and my native libary is not able to find the methode any longer?
What is my Problem here?

Comment: Is callStr a private method that is never called from Java? It could be removed from the class by some Java optimizer

Comment: Yes thank you, it got striped away by ProGuard. I added a -keep to the config file to keep the Methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obfuscation *per se* is not a problem, but ProGuard can remove "unused" methods. You can use `-keep` option or plant a fictional call to prevent striping of `callStr()`